# Disable paste mode entirely

Tags: cut-copy-paste, autocmd

I get what paste mode does for you, but I have never found it particularly useful.  I would like to completely deactivate it. I don't see an option to do so when looking at `:help paste`.  However, I figure this is doable with some combination of an auto-command and pastetoggle.

Could someone help me write this autocommand?  I can't find clear instructions on the Internet for this use case.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, but if you don't like paste mode then don't use it? I'm not sure if I follow why you want to "banish it to the depths of hell"? Are you triggering it accidentally somehow?

Comment: It goes into paste mode all the time

Comment: I'm probably on the wrong track. But worth a try is to check `set pastetoggle`

Comment: I'm also a little confused… What does `set pastetoggle` return? What does `set paste?` return? I've never experienced paste mode just happening 'all the time'. Are you on GUI vim? `set paste` related settings need to be set separately in `.gvimrc`, it gets reset in GUI. Not sure what, but something seems amiss here…

Comment: I too am curious. Is there a specific set of steps that causes `'paste'` to be switched on? Can you include this in the post? Or is the problem that something sets `'paste'` quietly and you don't know what's causing it? If so, you could use `:verbose set paste` to track down the offender.

Comment: Link the vimrc. And maybe a gif of what's happening. I don't actually understand how paste mode can be automatically toggled